# Source online for the melody of "yetziv pisgom" said in the Haftorah for second day Shavous

Tags: internet, song-poetry, music, shavuos, haftarah

Please can someone direct me to a source on-line for the melody of "[yetziv pisgom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Tov_Torah_readings#Yetziv_Pitgam)" said in the Haftorah for second day Shavous?

Comment: I've heard at least two tunes used for it, and suspect there are more. (Many existing tunes fit it.)

Comment: @msh210 Are you able please to identify the tunes you refer to, say by the first lines of the songs they are normally used for?

Comment: The tune I hear more often I've never heard to any other words, and the other tune I don't recall. Sorry. (Or did you mean my reference to "[m]any existing tunes"? Choose anything that fits "_Adon olam_" or "_D'ror yikra_".)

Comment: No idea, but now the tune used at my Shul is stuck in my head.

Comment: The one I've heard most often is the one linked to in [Shalom's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16625).

Comment: @msh210, You've never heard that tune (the one in Shalom's answer) used for *Adon Olam*? Go to a more yeshivish shul on a day they actually sing *Adon Olam* (usually only on Yom Tov); almost guaranteed they'll use that tune.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://archive.org/details/Yetziv_Pisgam

Is that the one you've heard?

Comment: Shalom, Thank you. I have heard that - and another one too.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qaN23CWvoc

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oehY6wnO6lU

Comment: @DoubleAA Chazzan Gluck is what I remember;  Stuart Izon's version is lovely. Thank you.